# Find and copy multiple pictures using powershell

Tags: image, powershell, file

I got a list on excel with picture names I have to find, is it in anyway possible to add the list to powershell and find the pictures and copy them out into one folder? 
The list is (about 1000)1310 pictures and there is a total of 44k pictures in aprox a ton of folders. I think maybe it was 500k folders.

[Picture of how the image software have made the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Hya.png)

[Exact number of files and folders, the last 14k pictures are in another main folder and not relevant for the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6egC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should take the [Tour] and you should (re-)read the help topic [Ask] to set your expectations on SO. .... the short answer would be "yes".  ... wait what? ... you have 44 thousand pictures spread over 500 thousand folders?

Comment: Thank you Olaf, I need more input to know how to make a pro question :) Walter's answer let's me get closer in my quest for the perfect question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+file+search+list

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) ... that's valid for some simple numbers as well

Answer (score -2):

Your question is very broad, and I can only give a very general answer.  This is clearly scriptable,  but it might take a lot of learning and a lot of effort.

First, you might want to consider what the relationship is between the way pictures are named inthe excel sheet and the way the picture files are named in the folders.
If they follow the same naming rules, that gets one big problem out of the way.

Next, you need to learn how to copy and excel table onto a Csv file.

Then you need to learn how to use Import-csv and feed the stream into a pipeline.

Then you need to process the output of the pipeline to a foreach loop that contains a copy-item cmdlet.

If there is a single master folder that contains all the other folders that contain pictures, then you are in luck.  Learn the -path, -recurse, and -include parameters.

Perhaps someone who has already dealt with the same problem can provide you with code.  But it may not do what you really want.